# How do I sort AWS SNS alert emails?

Tags: amazon-web-services, outlook, alert, amazon-sns

In outlook when I get an email from an AWS SNS topic it always comes from no-reply@sns.amazonaws.com. When it comes up in outlook the sender is either 'Dev-Environment-Alerts no-reply@sns.amazonaws.com' or 'Test-Environment-Alerts no-reply@sns.amazonaws.com' depending on where the alert came from. I cannot for the life of me figure out how to sort these nicely. I tried sorting by sender but that doesn't work. Any ideas?

There is nothing in the subject or body of the email that indicates what environment the alert came from.
I am using outlook.

Answer (score 0):

Is there anyway you can send to a different alias? So for example where foobar@example.com might have been the original send to foobar+dev@example.com?

This works for Gmail but not sure if it will work for your mail provider